# Show message after a successful record saving

Tags: c#, devexpress, blazor-server-side, xaf

I am new to XAF Blazor so I trying to display a message to end users after a successful record saving, so I wrote the following code:

```
public partial class MessageSavedSuccessfullyViewController : ViewController
{
    public MessageSavedSuccessfullyViewController()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnActivated()
    {
        base.OnActivated();
        View.ObjectSpace.Committing += ObjectSpace_Committing;
    }
    protected override void OnViewControlsCreated()
    {
        base.OnViewControlsCreated();
    }
    protected override void OnDeactivated()
    {
        View.ObjectSpace.Committing -= ObjectSpace_Committing;
        base.OnDeactivated();
    }
    private void ObjectSpace_Committing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (View.ObjectSpace.IsCommitting)
        {
            MessageOptions options = new();
            options.Duration = 2000;
            options.Message = string.Format("Record Saved Successfully");
            options.Type = InformationType.Success;
            options.Web.Position = InformationPosition.Right;
            options.Win.Caption = "Success";
            options.Win.Type = WinMessageType.Toast;
            Application.ShowViewStrategy.ShowMessage(options);
        }
    }
}
```

but when I run the code, nothing happens.
Is there something I am missing?
This code should be used across my entire application, not just in a specific view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public partial class MessageSavedSuccessfullyViewController : ViewController<DetailView>
{
    private string message;    
    public MessageSavedSuccessfullyViewController()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnActivated()
    {
        base.OnActivated();
        View.ObjectSpace.ObjectChanged += ObjectSpace_ObjectChanged;
        View.ObjectSpace.Committed += ObjectSpace_Committed;
    }
    protected override void OnViewControlsCreated()
    {
        base.OnViewControlsCreated();
    }
    protected override void OnDeactivated()
    {
        View.ObjectSpace.ObjectChanged -= ObjectSpace_ObjectChanged;
        View.ObjectSpace.Committed -= ObjectSpace_Committed;
        base.OnDeactivated();
    }
    void ObjectSpace_Committed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageOptions options = new();
        options.Duration = 2000;
        options.Message = message;
        options.Type = InformationType.Success;
        options.Web.Position = InformationPosition.Right;
        options.Win.Caption = "Success";
        options.Win.Type = WinMessageType.Toast;
        Application.ShowViewStrategy.ShowMessage(options);
        message = string.Empty;
    }
    void ObjectSpace_ObjectChanged(object sender, ObjectChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ObjectSpace.IsNewObject(e.Object))
        {
            message=string.Format("Record Saved Successfully");
        }
        else if (ObjectSpace.IsDeleting)
        {
            message = string.Format("Record Deleted Successfully");
        }
        else if (ObjectSpace.IsModified && e.OldValue != e.NewValue)
        {
            message = string.Format("Record Updated Successfully");
        }           
    }
}
```